# C++ Declaring dynamic arrary (unsigned char and struct) in a class?

Tags: c++

What is the proper way to declare a dynamic struct and unsigned char array within a class?

```
#define GENDER_MALE 0
#define GENDER_FEMALE 1

class c_House {
    public:
        c_House();

        c_House( unsigned int in_BedRoomCount,
                 short in_FloorCount,
                 const char* in_Address,
                 unsigned int in_PeopleCount ) :
                 BedRoomCount( in_BedRoomCount ),
                 FloorCount( in_FloorCount ),
                 Address( in_Address ),
                 PeopleCount( in_PeopleCount )
        {
            this->Array = new unsigned char[ in_BedRoomCount ];
            this->People = new PEOPLE[ in_PeopleCount ];
        };
        ~c_House() { delete[] this->Array; };
    // PROPERTIES
    private:
        struct PERSON {
            unsigned short Age;
            const char* Name;
            unsigned short Gender;
        };
        unsigned int BedRoomCount;
        short FloorCount;
        const char* Address;
        unsigned char* Array;
        unsigned int PeopleCount;
        PERSON *People;

    // ACTIONS
    private:
        void OpenGarage( bool in_Open );
        void Vacuum();
};
```

How should I be declaring a dynamic array (int and struct)?
I know this will be very dangerous - think about deep copy and so on:

```
this->Array = new unsigned char[ in_BedRoomCount ];
this->People = new PEOPLE[ in_PeopleCount ];
```

Is this the right way to delete an int array?

```
~c_House() { delete[] this->Array; };
```

How about struct array?

Comment: All of your identifiers with two adjacent underscores are reserved. The proper way is with a standard container, which already takes care of the issues.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you cannot use `std::vector<>` or `std::array<>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is to use `std::string` instead of the dynamic array of `char`, and `std::vector<PERSON>` instead of the dynamic array of `PERSON`.

If you have dynamically and manually allocated data in a class, you have to make sure that you follow [*the rule of three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), that is, implement a copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor to perform "deep copies" of the data. This is to ensure that each instance of your class owns its dynamically allocated data, and makes copying and assigning safe. In C++11, this is generalized to *the rule of five*.

An unrelated matter: names containing leading underscores, or double underscores anywhere, are reserved for the implementation. So you shouldn't give your variables names such as `in__PeopleCount`.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean beginners shouldn't attempt to understand how `string` and `vector` do their thing, i.e., *why* they are a better choice to begin with.

Comment: @EdS. that is right, but there is no need to create classes with many data members and nested structs to learn that.

Comment: The question here is "how do I manage dynamically allocated data".  The answer should be "this is how... now use these library types instead which do it for you"

Comment: I don't think this is a bad answer, "What is the proper way to declare a dynamic struct and unsigned char array within a class" and the answer "std::string and std::vector" is valid.

Comment: @EdS. I have elaborated a bit on the issue of dynamically allocated data management.

Comment: Leading underscores in the global scope, or followed by a capital anywhere.

Comment: @CLearner that one is OK. It is actually used quite often for data members.